# Execute script from docker Jenkins shell from remote server mounted on host

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

Strange title but it is what it is.

Basically I am trying to execute a python script, that is located on a remote server, through a Jenkins job. I have the location mounted on my local host. The Jenkins instance is running in a docker container in my local host. I was able to create a docker volume for the mounted folder.

The mount can be seen from both inside the host and the docker container.

Jenkins will not see the location that points at the script I'm trying to execute.

Shell content:

```
#!/bin/bash
python /path/to/my/script/on/remote/server/script.py
```

Error:

```
python: can't open file '/path/to/my/script/on/remote/server/script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: if you mounted it, the path should be in your localhost not on remote `python /path/to/my/script/on/myhost.py`